# Change coordinate origin in UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Is it possible to change the coordinate system in a UIView so that (0,0) will be the top right hand corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer bars the use of Interface Builder, but I know of no other way.

After initiating the UIView, perform a CGAffineTransform as such:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

Check the documentation for CGAffineTransform. You might also have to translate the view a bit, although I believe it should be good.

The "-1" up there inverts the x coordinate system. Whenever you present a new view programmatically, it will work as you hope.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0*0.0174532925);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f);`

should do it for you